# Extract text from xml file using javascript by avoiding some self closing tags of same name

Tags: javascript, xml

The XML file:

```
<bookstore>
    <book category="cooking">
        <title lang="en"><![CDATA[At any given place, at any given time of day or night, a failure may occur in a transmission and distribution system.]]></title>
        <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
    <book category="children">
        <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
        <author>J K. Rowling</author>
    <book category="web">
        <title lang="en" />XQuery Kick Start
        <author>James McGovern</author>
    <book category="web" cover="paperback">
        <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
        <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
</bookstore>
```

The HTML/JavaScript file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        myFunction(this);
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "Book.xml", true);
xhttp.send();

function myFunction(xml) {
    var x, i, xmlDoc, txt;
    xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
    txt = "";
    x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('title');
    for (i = 0 ; i <x.length; i++) {
        txt += x[i].childNodes[0].data + "<br>";
    }
    console.log(txt);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I just want to extract the text content of the `<title>` tag except that of the self closing title (the third title) tag.

When I'm trying that with my code it displays nothing and gives the following error:

> TypeError: x[i].childNodes[0] is undefined

Comment: What do you expect to be extracted from the 3rd title tag? Yes, it's self-closed and it contains no values!

Comment: Maybe you can pre-process the xml tags to fix untagged text or self-closing tags and then try to extract the information.

Comment: Try this: `txt += (x[i].childNodes && x[i].childNodes.length) ? x[i].childNodes[0].data + "<br>" : "";`, What this does is to make sure `x[i].childNodes[0]` is defined before trying to access any of its properties.

Comment: Thanks, Titus it worked!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```js
const
  xmlInput = `<bookstore>
       <book category="cooking">
           <title lang="en"><![CDATA[At any given place, at any given time of day or night, a failure may occur in a transmission and distribution system.]]></title>
           <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
       <book category="children">
           <title lang="en">
          Harry Potter
           </title>
           <author>J K. Rowling</author>
       <book category="web">
           <title lang="en" />XQuery Kick Start
           <author>James McGovern</author>
       <book category="web" cover="paperback">
           <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
           <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
    </bookstore>`;

function getXMLDocument(xmlString) {
  const
    parser = new DOMParser();
    
  return parser.parseFromString(xmlString,"application/xml");
}

function getTitleElementsFromDocument(xmlDocument) {
  const
      titleElements = xmlDocument.querySelectorAll('title');
      
  return Array.from(titleElements);
}

function createHTMLForTitles(titles) {
  return titles.reduce((html, title) => {  
      // Only add the title when it is not an empty string.
      if (title.textContent !== '') {
        html += `<li>${title.textContent}</li>`;
      }

      return html;
    }, '');
}

const
  xmlDocument = getXMLDocument(xmlInput),
  titleArray = getTitleElementsFromDocument(xmlDocument),
  titlesHTML = createHTMLForTitles(titleArray),
  outputElement = document.getElementById('output');
  
outputElement.innerHTML = titlesHTML;
```

```html
<ul id="output"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the `textContent` property of the `title` element node. This will work whether or not the node has any children, and it will also ignore any markup such as italics or subscripts or comments appearing within the text of the title element.